# Form with CollectionType not displaying uploadfile box

Tags: forms, file-upload

I am stuck with my create form not displaying the field of the embed form.

Quicky, I have two tables for each entity Trick and Image with a one to many relationship. I have an ImageType which is embed into the TrickType with a CollectionType, nothing fancy. THe ImageType has a subscriber to convert the File to an Image.

In the Form to create a new trick, I would normally have an upload file box but nothing shows up. I recently added the js supposing nothing is displayed because no picture is there in the database (it is a new trick) but it is the same, just adding new blank "div".

Here is the gist to check the code : https://gist.github.com/frogtube/069fb4e49ef8195cf2f9b9cccb5b8bfc

Many thanks for your helps guys,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO there is 2 problems in the js, you never select the dataprototype div [line 7 in my code](https://github.com/ismail1432/awesome/blob/master/public/js/addVisitor.js) and you never generate input in the dom.
Check my code and replace the $('div#booking_visitors'); with your image form id

Hope help